# Display data from two tables (cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

Creating an application using asp.net and code first that displays a heading, summary and some images for each entry in the database. I get this exception when I am trying to display the images:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: The entity or complex type 'FileUpload.Context.Support' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

The issue is with my `DisplaySummary` linq query and I am wondering how can I fix it so that it displays the summary and the related images.

Thanks for your help.

Controller:
I tried this in the controller but it doesn't work

```
public ActionResult Display()
    {
        var files = db.Supports.Select(d => new Support()
        {
            SupportId = d.SupportId,
            Name = d.Name,
            Summary = d.Summary,
            FileDetails = d.FileDetails.Select(x => new FileDetail()
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                FileName = x.FileName,
                Extension = x.Extension

            }).ToList()
        }).ToList();
        return View(files);
    }
```

View:

```
@model List<FileUpload.Models.Support>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@foreach (var p in Model)
{
    <h3>@p.Name</h3>
    <p>@p.Summary</p>
    foreach (var file in p.Files)
    {
        <img class="img-thumbnail" width="150" height="150" src="~/Images/@(file.FileName+file.Extension)" />
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Support
{

    public int SupportId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Your Name")]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Summary")]
    [Display(Name = "Summary")]
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FileDetail> FileDetails { get; set; }

}

public class FileDetail
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public int SupportId { get; set; }
    public virtual Support Support { get; set; }

}
```

Context:

```
public class EfDbcontext : DbContext
{
    public EfDbcontext()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Support> Supports { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FileDetail> FileDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you absolutely want to have `FileDetail`s without the correct value of `SupportId`, you can simply use

```
var files = db.Supports.Include(s => s.FileDetails).ToList();
```

Entity Framework doesn't allow creation of entity types directly in a LINQ expression. It wants to do it itself, probably to avoid tracking issues with incomplete entities.

Comment: Thank you Gert, very helpful response you fixed my issue